typescript eslint stops working when I add a rule
I've installed typescript-eslint and it works great when I have the following config:
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended
);

However, when I add a new rule to the config, it stops working entirely:
import eslint from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
  {
    rules: {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error",
    },
  }
);

I'm literally just following their docs. I have no clue why this is not working.

What does "stops working" mean? Are there any error messages?

This question doesn't provide enough information for anybody to confidently answer. What does "stops working" mean? What versions of eslint, typescript, and typescript-eslint are you on? If someone can't reproduce the issue you're seeing locally, and you don't say the error message, you can't expect any high confidence answers.
...all that being said, a hunch: the @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises rule requires linting with type information. You'll need to specify parserOptions.project or parserOptions.projectService in your ESLint config. See the linked docs for an explanation.

You need to enable typed linting.
From the docs:

Add TypeChecked to the name of any preset configs you're using, namely recommended, strict, and stylistic.
Add languageOptions.parserOptions to tell our parser how to find the TSConfig for each source file.

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parserOptions: {
        projectService: true,
        tsconfigRootDir: import.meta.dirname,
      },
    },
  },
);

